# Convert ps1 to exe and add parameters

Tags: powershell, scripting, exe, executable, ps1

Good day!

I have a ps1 script with this first line:
`param ($path)`

I need it to execute some command at the end of the script like:
`.\file.exe $path`

I know this is working because if I execute the `script.ps1 -path "some_path"` works fine.

The problem is, I'm using Powershell Packager (Ironman Software Powershell Packager) to convert the .ps1 into .exe file but when I try to run the `"script.exe -path "some_path"` is not working

Do you know how can I pass parameters to the exe file?

**EDIT: I WILL CLOSE THIS, SINCE I FOUND HOW TO DO IT DIRECTLY IN C#**

Thanks for your help

Comment: `script.exe "some_path"` ?

Comment: I tried and the execution gave me error because is trying to add the path after the last character in the script

Comment: Have you tried PS2EXE ?
https://github.com/MScholtes/PS2EXE

Comment: Yes, I do, but this software is detected as malware in my AV, I know is false positive, but cannot use it

Comment: ultimately it would be up to the packaging exe to map commandline parameters to the powershell script. Interally we have used ps2exe that we have continued to enhance on our side. We haven't specifically tried to do this, but if we were to, we would have to modify the c# code that is the "wrapper" console to translate the cmd parameters to powershell parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that those executables made by the software can receive parameters?

Is there a reason why you can’t just rewrite the scripts to prompt user input for a path once the executable runs?

Comment: It is because I want to add it to a C# code, the idea is to have an output from C# and add it to the exe file as paramenter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).